# MySQL Select By Newest Timestamp

Tags: mysql, select, timestamp

I've seen some similar types of questions on SO, however, I have not been able to find a solution to my specific issue.  (FYI, these are not my real columns, just a shortened example).

I have a basic table   `my_table`:

| user_1 | user_2 | timestamp | note(not part of table) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 25 | 2012-08-10 22:00:00 |  |
| 24 | 22 | 2012-08-10 19:00:00 | <=== I would like to return this row |
| 24 | 22 | 2012-08-10 17:00:00 |  |
| 21 | 17 | 2012-08-10 15:00:00 |  |

So, what I want to do is be able to:

```
 1) Select the "newest" row, based on timestamp AND 
 2) Select the 'user_2' column when given a value.
```

I have tried something like:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM my_table
 WHERE user_2 = 22
 AND timestamp = (
 SELECT MAX( timestamp )
 FROM my_table )
 LIMIT 1
```

But this does not return the row I am looking for. Any help on fixing this query would be great.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table -- standard stuff
   WHERE user_2 = 22 -- predicate
   ORDER BY timestamp DESC -- this means highest number (most recent) first
   LIMIT 1; -- just want the first row
```

---

*Edit:*

By the way, in case you're curious why your original query didn't work, let's break down the pieces:

- select some stuff from `my_table`...
- where `user_2` = 22
- and `timestamp` = *(some value, let's put it aside for now)*
- limit 1

Now, coming back to that `timestamp` value, it comes from your subquery:

```
SELECT MAX( timestamp ) FROM my_table
```

Note that this subquery doesn't restrict any rows based on `user_2` -- it asks for what's the max timestamp *in the whole table*. That max timestamp is the first one in your table above: (user_1 = 23, user_2 = 25, timestamp = 2012-08-10 22:00:00).

So, let's plug that back to the top-level query:

- select some stuff from `my_table`...
- where user_2 = 22
- and timestamp = **2012-08-10 22:00:00**
- limit 1

... and you can see there isn't such a row.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I was making this way too hard on myself.  That's what I get for being awake the last 36 hours.  :-)

Comment: @Dodinas You're welcome! I find that coming from non-SQL programming, where we're taught over and over to break the problem into smaller problems, there's a tendency to do the same in SQL queries. Unfortunately, that often ends them up as *more* complex -- and less efficient, too. It's a mental switch that takes a bit to get the hang of. Btw, I edited my question to explain a bit as to where your original query got into trouble.

Comment: Terrific! That helps very much. Thanks again.

Comment: Hahaha, this was genius.  +1 for simplicity.

Comment: I am wondering about the performance of that query when MANY (say 100K+) rows are there. The engine needs to sort everything before returning the first item of that list. If I create an index on the timestamp column, would the engine be intelligent enough to navigate the btree to find the one element I am looking for, instead of doing  the whole sort?

Comment: Yup, that's one of the main uses for an index. You can verify with `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` In this case, you'd want an index on `(user_2, timestamp)`. Going left-to-right, an index can satisfy as many equalities as you want, and then ordering. Without the `user_2` column in the index, thte engine would have to scan the timestamp index until it found a row with the right `user_2`.

Answer (score 5):

If someone has a similar problem in SQL Server, this will work for you (the suggested MySQL query in the previous post doesn't work in SQL Server):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE    timestamp =  ( SELECT MAX( timestamp ) FROM my_table 
                        WHERE user_2 = 22 )
```

Comment: I came to the same solution, however, having a large table, even with indexes on timestamp, the query is very very slow. Any smarter way around?

Answer (score 5):

Another method is to `GROUP BY` the `user_2` column as you calculate `MAX(timestamp)`. Doing so will make `MAX(timestamp)` calculate not the latest date in the entire table, but rather the latest timestamp **for each group** of records with the same `user_2` value.

So, for example, your query could be:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE user_2 = 22
AND timestamp =
  (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM my_table
   WHERE user_2 = 22
   GROUP BY user_2)
LIMIT 1;
```

This query is adapted from the answer I found in [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14544472/473792).

Comment: What advantage does this add to the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is all i got.

```
SELECT timestamp 
       FROM my_table 
       WHERE user_22 = '22' 
       ORDER BY timestamp DESC /*or ASC*/
```

And when you query it the codewould be

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array(the sql query)){
$timestamp = $row['timestamp']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found to this problem:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM my_table AS t1
 WHERE user_2 = 22
 AND timestamp = (
 SELECT MAX( timestamp )
 FROM my_table AS t2
 WHERE t1.user_2 = t2.user_2 );
```

Simply Remove `WHERE user_2 = 22` if you want to see the latest timestamp for each unique user.