# MySQL Select Group of Records Based on latest timestamp

Tags: mysql, select, timestamp

I have a routine that runs every few hours that creates several entries in a table used for logging.  What I need to do is select all the records with the most recent **timestamp** that have a common account id. Something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_logs 
WHERE ACCOUNT_ID='12345' 
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
```

Where I'm stuck is that I can't say `LIMIT 5` or something like that because the number of records created at each routine interval could be different. So, for example, when the routine runs at 10AM, it may create 6 table entries and only 4 table entries at 2PM.

Is there a way to select the grouping of the latest records without knowing how many there are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean multiple entries in your Table_Logs table could have the same timestamp and you want to return each of those that were entered most recently, you need to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Max(TimeStamp) maxTime
FROM Table_Logs
WHERE Account_Id = '12345'
GROUP BY Field1, Field2
```

Field1, etc. are the fields you want to return in Table_Logs.

Here is some sample [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1a8c/1) to try out.

Good luck.

Comment: That worked perfectly - thank you!  One quick question - right now the timestamps for each interval are identical (i.e., 2013-01-27 08:00:01).  If for some reason the entries span a few seconds (i.e, 2013-01-27 08:00:01, 2013-01-27 08:00:02) will this still work or will only only select the 08:00:02 entry?

Comment: I just ran it in Fiddle and changed a few of the timestamps by a few seconds and it seemed to work!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to group by the timestamp. Assuming that all the ones entered at 10am had the same timestamp, and 2 pm, ditto, would be something like:

```
  SELECT timestamp, Field1, Field2
    FROM Table_Logs
GROUP BY timestamp
```

If your timestamps are too precise, simply do a substring:

```
  SELECT LEFT(timestamp, 5), Field1, Field2
    FROM Table_Logs
GROUP BY LEFT(timestamp, 5)
```

Assuming the timestamp is a string (log file). If not, you have to stringify it.