# group by and select last records depending on timestamp created

Tags: php

I have a table which contains records

```
id  note    date    timestamp
1   ABCD    2014-08-18  2014-08-18 08:33:49
2   ABCDE   2014-08-18  2014-08-18 08:33:49
3   ABCDEF  2014-08-19  2014-08-18 08:33:49
4   XYZ     2014-08-19  2014-08-19 15:25:15
5   ABCD    2014-08-20  2014-08-19 15:25:15
6   ABCD    2014-08-19  2014-08-20 19:30:02
```

I need to group on "note" & select values created by last timestamp.

My expected output should be:

```
id  note    date    timestamp
2   ABCDE   2014-08-18  2014-08-18 08:33:49
3   ABCDEF  2014-08-19  2014-08-18 08:33:49
4   XYZ     2014-08-19  2014-08-19 15:25:15
6   ABCD    2014-08-19  2014-08-20 19:30:02
```

I am using query

`SELECT Field1, Field2, Max(TimeStamp) maxTime FROM table GROUP BY Field1`

from post "[MySQL Select Group of Records Based on latest timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544183/mysql-select-group-of-records-based-on-latest-timestamp)"

But the query selects last time stamp, but the date field will be of previous record..

Please check the SQL fiddle :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92a0ab/1 and let me know where i am wrong, or can somebody help me with correct query!!!

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS a GROUP BY a.note ORDER BY a.timestamp
```

I think it help for you :)